# Deriving $\neg R$ from $\{R↔(R∨(P∧¬P)), R↔¬P, ¬P→(P↔(Q→Q)), P→Q\}$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Give a derivation of $\neg R$ from the following premises:
>
> $$\{R\leftrightarrow(R\lor(P\land \neg P)), R\leftrightarrow\neg P, \neg P\to(P\leftrightarrow(Q\to Q)), P\to Q\}$$
>
> using the rules found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwKJI9kcD_sbRFRsclFfczJtWmM/edit?usp=sharing).

I don't know where to start...

Edit:

> 1 1) R↔(R/lor(P∧¬P)) P
>
> 2 2) R↔¬P P
>
> 3 3) ¬P→(P↔(Q→Q))  P
>
> 4 4)P→Q P
>
> 5 5)R P
>
> 2 6)R→¬P  2,BE
>
> 2,5 7)¬P 5,6,MP
>
> 2,3 8)P↔(Q→Q) 3,7,MP
>
> 2,3 9)(Q→Q)→P 8,BE
>
> 2,3,5 10)¬(Q→Q) 7,9,MT
>
> 2,3,5 11)Q∧¬Q 10,NC
>
> 2,3,5 12)Q 11,simp
>
> 2,3,5 12)¬Q 11,simp
>
> 2,3 14)¬R 12,13,RAA
>
> 2,15)¬R 5,14,RAA

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Here's a quick guide on how to write math on this site: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Your reasoning seems sound, and follows more or less the same path as Hunan's answer below. Personally, I would conclude from premise 3 and the appropriate rules that $P$ (premise $3$ can be simplified to $\lnot P \rightarrow P$), and then premise 2 is equivalent to $\lnot R \leftrightarrow P$ so you can deduce that $\lnot R$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your premises are:

1. $R \leftrightarrow (R \lor (P \land \lnot P))$
2. $R \leftrightarrow \lnot P$
3. $\lnot P \rightarrow (P \leftrightarrow (Q \rightarrow Q))$
4. $P \rightarrow Q$

You want to prove $\lnot R$, so suppose, for contradiction, that $R$. That with (2) gives us $\lnot P$, which with (3) gives us $(P \leftrightarrow (Q \rightarrow Q))$, which implies that $((Q \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow P)$. This with $\lnot P$ gives us $\lnot (Q \rightarrow Q)$ $\equiv \lnot (\lnot Q \lor Q) \equiv \lnot (\top) \equiv \bot$. Therefore we conclude that $\lnot R$.

That's just a sketch. I've used proof by contradiction, $\leftrightarrow$-elimination, the definition of '$\leftrightarrow$', modus tollens, modus ponens, the definition of '$\rightarrow$', and the fact that $(\lnot Q \lor Q)$ is a tautology. Let me know if you're having trouble adapting it to Chellas' system. It shouldn't be too difficult. For example, $\leftrightarrow$-elimination is called 'BE' there, modus tollens has the suggestive 'MT' label, and so on.

Comment: hello, can you check above if it is correct? I think the dependence columns are wrong.

Comment: The steps and their justifications are correct, but since I'm not too familiar with Lemmon-style proofs, I recommend that you check the dependencies in some proof-checker to make sure.

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it all looks, roughly speaking, good.

But for stylistic purposes, you usually want to call your "P (premise)": which you introduce on line $5$, an assumption. So $R$ is an assumption "A". Indent the assumption and the *sub-proof* of all that follows from the assumption, $5$, until and including your arrival at the contradiction, RAA.

You can also introduce RAA immediately after obtaining $Q \land \lnot Q$ which forms your contradiction $\perp$. Then your subproof ends, and you can conclude $\lnot R$. Some proof systems refer to the invocation of $\lnot R$ as "negation introduction".  That is, you need only one invocation of RAA.