# Deriving ¬R from {R↔(R∨(P∧¬P)),R↔¬P,¬P→(P↔(Q→Q)),P→Q}

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Give a derivation of $\neg R$ from the following premises:
>
> $$\{R\leftrightarrow(R\lor(P\land \neg P)), R\leftrightarrow\neg P, \neg P\to(P\leftrightarrow(Q\to Q)), P\to Q\}$$
>
> using the rules found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwKJI9kcD_sbRFRsclFfczJtWmM/edit?usp=sharing).

My assignment is due today, if someone can help me out. ty
Is this correct? I know some dependence columns are wrong.

> 1 1) R↔(R/lor(P∧¬P)) P
>
> 2 2) R↔¬P P
>
> 3 3) ¬P→(P↔(Q→Q))  P
>
> 4 4)P→Q P
>
> 5 5)R P
>
> 2 6)R→¬P  2,BE
>
> 2,5 7)¬P 5,6,MP
>
> 2,3 8)P↔(Q→Q) 3,7,MP
>
> 2,3 9)(Q→Q)→P 8,BE
>
> 2,3,5 10)¬(Q→Q) 7,9,MT
>
> 2,3,5 11)Q∧¬Q 10,NC
>
> 2,3,5 12)Q 11,simp
>
> 2,3,5 12)¬Q 11,simp
>
> 2,3 14)¬R 12,13,RAA
>
> 2,15)¬R 5,14,RAA

Comment: You asked the exact same question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546585/deriving-neg-r-from-rrpp-rp-ppqq-pq). If there is anything more you want related to that question, you should add commentaries or edit there, not ask the same question again.